# How to escape characters in a ftp url

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ftp, spark-csv

I am using spark for fetching a file from ftp server using the following code

```
val dataSource = "ftp://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<path>"
sc.addFile(dataSource)
var fileName = SparkFiles.get(dataSource.split("/").last)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
  .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .load(fileName)
```

but i am facing the problem of escaping characters like '^', '!', '@' or '#' etc etc. I tried using the HEX ASCII values for the special characters and tried to escape them by surrounding the username/password in escape quotes for example

```
val dataSource = "ftp://\'<username>\':\'<password>\'.........
```

but this didn't work either. Can anyone please explain to me how I can escape such characters in my ftp url ?

P.S., this code does work when the password doesn't contain any special characters.

Comment: Is it fine to just download the file and save it in the local disk then use Spark to parse it?

Comment: well that will be the last thing I would go for because it has its own complexities while downloading the file.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that it's a URL. That means it can include % escapes. For example an anonymous ftp site requires an email address as password, so it would look like

> ftp://anonymous:user%40foo.com@source.com/path/to/file